# Searching a single Excel column for a keyword returns only the first cell details

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an excel sheet with two colums. Col A is a list of hostnames. Col B says either True OR False. I am using below script to search for FALSE and get respective cell row and column numbers. But it returns only the very first cell which contains FALSE and ends there. Do I need to tell it to loop/recurse or something like that?

Heres my code:

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\temp\extest3.xlsx")
$sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

$getStatus = $sheet.UsedRange.find("False")
$cellrow = $getStatus.Row
$cellcol = $getstatus.Column
$celladdress = $cellrow,$cellcol
$celladdress 
$workbook.Save()
$workbook.Close()
```

The output I get is only one cell row and col number. Not getting other cells which contains false.

Comment: Create a foreach loop and iterate the column of hostnames based on the conditional check (If/else) of the corresponding next cell where you can pick the values as true or false.

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to use the Excel Com Object with PowerShell as [AdminOfThings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11025476/adminofthings) good answer shows,
it is (especially for simple flat data structures) quite clumsy ***and*** requires Excel to be installed locally.

I suggest to use [Doug Finke](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)s famous [ImportExcel](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel) module.

Just for demonstration create a sample `.xlsx` file:

```
# generate test file with random data
1..10|ForEach-Object{
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        HostName = 'Test{0:D2}' -f $_
        Online   = [bool](0..1|Get-Random)
    }
} | Export-Excel .\extest3.xlsx
```

---

```
HostName Online
-------- ------
Test01    False
Test02    False
Test03     True
Test04     True
Test05     True
Test06    False
Test07    False
Test08     True
Test09     True
Test10     True
```

And output the HostNames with `False` in the next column what I presume is what you want:

```
Import-Excel .\extest3.xlsx | 
  Where-Object {-not $_.Online} | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostName
```

---

```
Test01
Test02
Test06
Test07
```

Comment: This solution would be easier to work with if installing modules is possible. I personally do not like working with the Excel Com Object. +1

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not supposed to install any modules.

Comment: Not supposed to install any modules? That's like eating an Oreo cookie and the filling is missing. ;-) +10 on ImportExcel

Answer (score 2):

You can continue using the `Find()` method with the *After* parameter. A while loop with a `break` statement can be used to halt the search once you return to the top of the sheet.

```
$getStatus = $sheet.UsedRange.Find("False")
$firstrow = $getStatus.Row
$firstcol = $getstatus.Column
$celladdress = $firstrow,$firstcol
$celladdress

while ($getStatus) {
    $getStatus = $sheet.UsedRange.Find("False",$getStatus)
    $cellrow = $getStatus.Row
    $cellcol = $getstatus.Column
    $celladdress = $cellrow,$cellcol
    if ($celladdress[0] -eq $firstrow) {
        break
    }
    $celladdress
}
```

The value of the *After* parameter is always `$getStatus`.